# Function missing 1 required positional argument: 'lst'

Tags: python, function, arguments

I am new to Python and I have a test to write a programm that calculates mean and standard deviation of Gaussian distribution.
My program works fine but I got the message that my function is

```
missing 1 required positional argument: 'lst'
```

I have tried different possibilities and google but I do not understand the error message. Can someone help me please? Below is my code:

```
import random
import statistics


def gaussian_distribution(lst):
    mean = 100
    sigma = 10
    counter = 3
    for i in range(0, counter):
        temp = random.gauss(mean, sigma)
        lst.append(temp)
        st_dev = statistics.stdev(lst)
    average = statistics.mean(lst)
    return average, st_dev


returnvalues = []
liste = [0]

returnvalues = gaussian_distribution(liste)

print("Mean: ", returnvalues[0])
print("Standard Deviation: ", returnvalues[1])
```

Comment: Please give a complete error message. The problem cannot be located from the code you currently provide.

Comment: please provide the code details in the function `def gaussian_distribution(lst):`

Comment: Do you call the function from another place in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to provide a list of numbers, not just `liste = [0]`. Try this:

```
from statistics import mean, stdev

def gaussian_distribution(lst):
    return mean(lst), stdev(lst)

liste = [95,85,80,70,60]
m, sd = gaussian_distribution(liste)
print('The mean is', m)
print('The standard deviation is', sd)
```

Output

```
The mean is 78
The standard deviation is 13.509256086106296
```

**Edit:** With OP's updated code, I've made some modifications.

First, I've increased the counter to 30, which is the minimum for the approximation to Normal distribution.

Second, the variable `st_dev` should be outside the for-loop, so that it applies to the final list (of 30 elements).

Third, there is no need to parse any list to the function `gaussian_distribution()` as it is designed to generate its own list of normally distributed random numbers.

```
import random
import statistics

def gaussian_distribution():
    lst = []
    mean = 100
    sigma = 10
    counter = 30
    for i in range(0, counter):
        temp = random.gauss(mean, sigma)
        lst.append(temp)
    st_dev = statistics.stdev(lst)
    average = statistics.mean(lst)
    return average, st_dev

returnvalues = list(gaussian_distribution())
print("Mean: ", returnvalues[0])
print("Standard Deviation: ", returnvalues[1])
```

Output

```
Mean:  101.2713393570188
Standard Deviation:  12.32980977675229
```

Comment: This is not true. Take a look at the following piece of code: `def avg(lst): return sum(lst)/len(lst)` It works perfectly fine for lists with only one item.

Comment: hi @TDG, yes it's correct your code works for mean; however variance requires at least two data points :-)

Comment: Yes, but we don't know how the op wrote his code, and it looks like we are more concerned about it than he is...

Comment: yes it's true, I only presume that the function `gaussian_distribution(lst)` (ie, normal distribution) aims to calculate the mean and standard deviation. Let's see what the OP says when he reads the post later

Comment: When I call the function gaussian_distribution(lst) the first time I can not provide a list of  numbers because the numbers are created inside the function. 
I pasted the completed code above.

Comment: hi @kangaroo.dundee i've appended my solution based on your updated code. Please let me have your feedback, thanks!

Comment: @BlackRaven based on your explanations (step 1-3) I understood what I did wrong. Thanks a lot!